# 401 error while calling minecrafts name avalability api

Tags: python, minecraft

```
def check_username():
    username = username_entry.get().strip()
    url = f"https://api.minecraftservices.com/minecraft/profile/name/{username}/available"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        messagebox.showwarning("Username Taken", f"Sorry, the username '{username}' is taken!")
    elif response.status_code == 204:
        messagebox.showinfo("Username Available", f"The username '{username}' is available!")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Error checking username '{username}': {response.status_code}")
```

not sure what I'm missing, already checked https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API but I don't seem to find a solution

Comment: `401` is `Unauthorized`. It doesn't look like you're providing an API key.

Comment: @Barmar can you please tell me what sort of key, like a bearer token?

Comment: Possibly, I'm not really familiar with this API. Most public APIs require either a bearer token in the HTTP header, or an explicit token in the API parameters.

Comment: The documentation you linked to says the Mojang API was shut down in 2021.

Comment: Have you fully read and tried any of the API documentation in the wiki.vg/Mojang_API?
They have a whole wrapper section and fully fleshed documentation. Plus the suggestions elsewhere in this question (what seems to be a better alternative to that documentation in particular) https://mojang-api-docs.gapple.pw/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using that API endpoint, use this one:

[https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{username}](https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/%7Busername%7D)

Just make your code check for the "id" or "name" values in the response data to see if the name is taken. If it's not taken the endpoint will return:

```
"errorMessage" : "Couldn't find any profile with name {username}"
```

Also, for future reference, the API docs you're using are absolutely horrible, use this one instead:

https://mojang-api-docs.gapple.pw/